# Can I put Windows update uninstall folders on a different drive?

Tags: windows-update

I have to a VM set up with Windows XP, the C: drive is 15 Gb and is running out of space,
a lot of space is taken up by the $NtUninstall folders in C:\Windows, eg $NtUninstallKB960225$

[Somewhat related question here seems to indicate deletion is an option](https://superuser.com/questions/140/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-installs-updates-to-litter-my-hard-drive-with-cryptic-f) but that would stop me from un-installing the updates in future.

If I copy these folders to another drive would uninstall still work, if I were to copy them back later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy them to your backup location, if you need to delete an update, move the appropiate folder back to it's original position

Answer (score 2):

If your file sytem on the C: drive is NTFS, you can add a new drive to the system and mount it as a folder in your C: drive (see [this explanation](http://www.watchingthenet.com/mount-partition-as-folder-in-windows.html) for details). That way the fact that you have two actual (well, in this case virtual) hard drives is hidden from the system, they appear to be only one drive.

This approach is more flexible than [smok1's proposal](https://superuser.com/questions/22226/can-i-put-windows-update-uninstall-folders-on-a-different-drive/22230#22230), as compression will not free *that* much space, and you would run into the same problem again after a couple of hundred more updates. Also, there is no need for manual copying as in [Ivo's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/22226/can-i-put-windows-update-uninstall-folders-on-a-different-drive/22234#22234).

It's possible that this feature is limited to XP Professional and does not work in XP Home, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why copy? Compress them with best available tool you have, so you will save a lot of space. Thus, you will be able to restore them when needed.

After compression feel free to move them to any place you need.

Answer (score 0):

Back up the VM by copying the virtual disk file out somewhere else. Then you can delete those folders. If you hit a problem, put the safe copy of the virtual disk file back. That's the best option to save space on the VM virtual disk.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot with VirtualBox, delete all the `$NtUninstall`* files, check everything is ok, then *clone* the VM and import it again.