# Undeletable Folders

Tags: windows, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)

I have 3 Folders on my D: - Drive they seem to be auto-generated by Windows their names are:

```
14fa8480d76dbc64935b9f176a 
716a7cc8ac101b4e55a4
842bfe398b7b63d2105cfc8225
```

Only the SYSTEM User has access to them. What are the folders used for? How can I delete them?

Thank you for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](http://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive), also http://superuser.com/questions/423766/how-do-i-delete-left-over-windows-update-folders, http://superuser.com/questions/140/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-installs-updates-to-litter-my-hard-drive-with-cryptic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these instructions:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/when-i-try-to-delete-some-folders-an-error-message/800326ee-5d55-4ef9-ac67-b5e1669989a5

> Note: here, 'folder' as a subject refers to the folder that you want
>   to delete.
>
> Step 1: Get access to the built-in administrator account, which you
>   can do by following these steps:
>               a. Go to Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools
>               b. On the left panel, go to Local Users and Groups > Users; you should now see a list of users on your computer
>               c. Right-click the Administrator account which shows up in the list and go to Properties
>               d. Uncheck 'Account is Disabled' and confirm by pressing OK
>
> Step 2: Log on to your newly-enabled administrator account
>
> Step 3: Now we begin setting-up the security settings that will allow
>   you to delete that folder that was (perhaps) once owned by SYSTEM:
>               I'll make an assumption that you want to delete a folder and all its sub-folders along
>               a. Right-click the folder
>               b. Go to the Security tab on the top
>               c. Click the Advanced button that's at the bottom
>
> Step 4: The first part of setting-up the security settings is to set
>   the owner of the folder:
>               a. Go to the Owner tab on the top
>               b. Click the Edit button that's at the bottom
>               c. There should be a list of accounts to pick from to change ownership to, this is located under the label 'Change owner
>   to:'
>               d. The entry 'Administrator (YOURCOMPUTERNAME\Administrator)' should be there; if not then we have
>   to add it into the list:
>                   - Click the 'Other users or groups...' button that's at the bottom
>                   - Under the label 'Enter the object name to select (examples):', there should be a text field that you can type in; type
>   in 'Administrator' (without the quotes of course)
>                   - Click the 'Check Names' button that's on the right; 'Administrator (YOURCOMPUTERNAME\Administrator)' should now be there
>   *by itself*; well if not, then you have to delete the line which does not represent the administrator account you're in right now
>                   - Confirm by pressing OK; it'll now appear on the list of accounts you can select from
>               e. Now select 'Administrator (YOURCOMPUTERNAME\Administrator)' from that list
>               f. Check 'Replace owner on subcontainers and objects' to propagate our change
>               g. Press OK to confirm; a message should now pop-up, indicating that you have to re-open Properties. Do so by pressing on
>   all the OK buttons you see
>
> Step 5: Now that we've set the owner of the folder, we're still not
>   done. There's one key step left which is to remove inheritable
>   permissions:
>               a. Repeat step 3 to get to re-open Properties and get to 'Advanced Security Settings'
>               b. Go to the Permissions tab on the top
>               c. Click the 'Change Permissions' button that's at the bottom
>               d. At the bottom, there should be 2 checkboxes:
>                   - 'Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent': Un-check this; when you do so, you'll get a warning about
>   parent settings not being able to propagate. Select 'Add'
>                   - 'Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object': Check-this
>               e. Confirm by pressing OK. Windows will warn you again this time; hit OK
>               f. Confirm again by pressing OK; now you should arrive at Properties again
>
> Now you should not have any warnings about SYSTEM not giving you
>   permission while trying to perform actions on that folder. All the
>   checkboxes for changing permissions on accounts (Properties>Security>
>   Edit) should now be enabled, and you can tinker around with it.

Answer (score 1):

they are uninstall packages for windows updates installed on your system. usually they are large packages like service packs. you need them if you wish to rollback or uninstall the update, but can otherwise be deleted if you need the space.